# OpsCenter is unable to backup data due to lack of sudo permissions

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-14.04, datastax-enterprise

I see someone had a similar issue about a year ago, but the solution at the bottom of the page doesn't seem to work for me.
http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/data-backups-permissions-error

It says the following worked:

```
usermod -a -G cassandra opscenter-admin
```

I get an error that the opscenter-admin user doesn't exist.

The directory I use for my data directory in Cassandra is not the default setting. I mount an external drive and I remember having to grant the Cassandra user access to it when I first set it up. I'm thinking I need to grant the OpsCenter user access as well, but I'm not sure what the user is called seeing that the above doesn't work.

**Here is the error I'm getting:**

[image]

**And here are the permissions on my data directory:**

[image]

**I even tried giving Cassandra user sudo privilege per a suggestion in comments:**

[image]

Comment: at some point along the way since that previous post, the opscenter changed so that it's now run by the cassandra user/group not the opscenter/opscenter-admin user/group. That older solution won't work. and you're not showing the permissions on the /data folder itself.

Comment: Far as I can tell my cassandra user already has access.

Comment: True LHWizard. in 5.1 I believe we went to cassandra user. You don't need opscenter-... user. What about the permissions of the files inside the snapshots (per the error message)? Also, is cassandra in sudoers?

Comment: See my updated question with new screenshot. I gave my cassandra user sudo privileges but the same error occurs. Oddly too I can't use sudo su to change to cassandra user.

Comment: sudo su - cassandra -s /bin/bash ?

Comment: yes that worked for switching to cassandra user -- thanks :) -- but still not sure why opscenter is giving the error.